# Reading .mht webpages from jetty server

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some .mht files which load fine from local files but when loaded from the jetty webserver display as junk text.

What can I do to make them work correctly from our webserver? I know that for Apache server I need to add the below lines of code to .htaccess file. But how do I make similar changes for Jetty? I am using Intellij IDE

```
     <IfModule mod_mime.c> 
        # MIME HyperText Markup Language (MHTML) markup 
        AddType text/html .mhtml .mht .maff .maf 
        AddType message/rfc822 .mhtml .mht 
        AddType multipart/related .mhtml .mht .maff .maf 
     </IfModule>
```